# DS link to content - how to change the link?

Tags: views, display-suite

I am using D7. I want to do simple thing with Views and DS: I have view with list of content type teasers and another view with list of the same content type full articles. In DS there is an option to link teaser's Title to it's content, so when pressed user can get the full content of that content type. But I want all teaser titles to link to the same page - to the View with all content types listed.

Do I have to alter any tpl for this, or is there any other way to do this?
Maybe it will sound silly, but I really don't get it, so please help me :)

thank you!
Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe display suite extras can help you achieve this with a combination of tokens.

1. After you enable the Display Suite Extras you could go to admin/structure/ds/fields and create a new code field.
2. Label your code field and tell you will be using tokens.

[image: Field code in display suite]

3 In manage Display of your content type disable the title and enable your new field that it was created by Display Suite Extras.

This tutorial helped me in doing something similar that you are trying to do. 
[Customize ULR/link display suite and tokens](http://deeson-online.co.uk/labs/customised-urllink-term-tokens-display-suite) . I hope it helps :)